# How to customise update method for ManyToMany fields in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, put

I have a few models with ManyToMany relationships between them and I need to override the create and update method to make the POST and PUT request work in DRF.

Here's my code so far:

```
class CreateFolderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Folder
        fields = ("id", "title", "description", "users")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        users = validated_data.pop(
            'users') if 'users' in validated_data else []
        folder = Folder.objects.create(**validated_data)
        folder.users.set(users)
        return folder
```

This create method works perfectly.

I tried re-creating the same logic for the update method, but it doesn't work:

```
class FolderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    documents = DocumentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Folder
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        users = validated_data.pop('users') if 'users' in validated_data else []
        instance.users.set(users)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

When I send a PUT request, the object does not get modified at all, it gets deleted altogether.

Any clue?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Don' t set `documents` as `read_only`:

```py
documents = DocumentSerializer(many=True)
```

By calling `instance.users.set(users)`, you replace the precedent list, for example if you pass an empty list all associated users are removed. So if you want to leave the current users associated you need to insert their primary keys in the request data (for the users key), otherwise use `instance.users.add` instead of `instance.users.set`.